# msvcr110d.dll!memcpy error while testing structures and arrays

Tags: c++, arrays, dll, c++11, structure

I was wondering if anyone could take a look at why I'm getting runtime errors here.

> First-chance exception at 0x6FBDEBC2 (msvcr110d.dll) in Project1.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x7CB67DEB. Unhandled
>   exception at 0x6FBDEBC2 (msvcr110d.dll) in Project1.exe: 0xC0000005:
>   Access violation writing location 0x7CB67DEB.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    struct person {
        string name;
        int age;
        int weight;
        string nickname;
    } ;

    person people[1];

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(people); i++){
        string s[4];
        for(int x = 0; x < 4; x++){
            cout << "Please enter person " << i << "'s " << (x == 0 ? "name" : x == 1 ? "age" : x == 2 ? "weight" : x == 3 ? "nickname" : "unknown") << "." << endl;
            getline(cin, s[x]);
        }
        people[i].name = s[0];
        stringstream(s[1]) >> people[i].age;
        stringstream(s[2]) >> people[i].weight;
        people[i].nickname = s[3];
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(people); i++)
        cout << "Person " << i << ": name = " << people[i].name << ", age = " << people[i].age << ", weight = " << people[i].weight << ", nickname = " << people[i].nickname << endl; 

    cout << "Please press enter to continue.";
    fflush(stdin);
    cin.clear();
    cin.get();
}
```

It works out just fine up until the second for loop, where it appears to run the error.

Comment: `sizeof(people)`???  C'mon - you know better than that :)  SUGGESTION: use std::vector instead of an array.  IMHO...

Comment: For starters, `sizeof(people)` is bytes, not elements.

Comment: I'm an idiot! Thanks, just learning C++ from Java!

Answer (score 3):

Your problem lies here:

```
sizeof(people)
```

This does not give you the length of the `people` array, but the total size of the array in bytes. You can use `std::begin(people)` and `std::end(people)` to get iterators to the beginning and one past the end of the array.

```
for (auto it = std::begin(people); it != std::end(people); ++it)
{
  // it is an iterator to an element of people
  it->name = ....;
}
```

Alternatively, you can use a range based loop:

```
for (auto& p : people)
{
  // p is a reference to an element of people here
  p.name = ....;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To prevent this kind of issue, consider this approach, which allows you to store the size of a static array:

```
int ARRAY_SIZE = 1;
person people[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

Then your `for` loop:

```
for(int i = 0; i < ARRAY_SIZE; i++)
```

Comment: Careful, the size of an array must be a compile time constant (in `C++`).